# Making an image width:100% inside a inline-block element

Tags: css

If I have an image on a page with width set to 100% in css it is as wide as the browser. Fine. However, if I make a containing div have display:inline-block, then the image is no longer set to have a width:100%. Instead, it just shows as the actual width of the image:

```css
img {width:100%;}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/0c9109c71ea0524d9fe840f91fabd67bb94a26a9/r=537&c=0-0-534-712/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2013/05/30/1369920769000-grumpycat-1305300933_3_4.jpg"/>

<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <img src="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/0c9109c71ea0524d9fe840f91fabd67bb94a26a9/r=537&c=0-0-534-712/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2013/05/30/1369920769000-grumpycat-1305300933_3_4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

So, basically, the inline-block containing div wants to be as wide as its contents, and the width:100% on the image wants to be as wide as the containing element, so it seems they are both confused and just defaulting to the width of the image. I know I can set the width of the containing div to be 100% and have the desired outcome, but for what I am actually doing, that is not an option. Is there any way to force the img to be 100% width with only css on the image itself? I guess I am basically trying to set a class on a parent of an element, which I do not think is possible... Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is because a percentage value on [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property) is relative to the width of the box's containing block. While a block-level container (`<div>` element, for instance) takes the entire width of its containing block, an inline-level element doesn't.

Therefore you have to specify the width of the wrapper `<div>` explicitly. As a thumb rule, when you say `100%` you should ask yourself `100%` of what?

```css
img { width:100%; }
div { display:inline-block; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<img src="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/0c9109c71ea0524d9fe840f91fabd67bb94a26a9/r=537&c=0-0-534-712/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2013/05/30/1369920769000-grumpycat-1305300933_3_4.jpg"/>
<div>
  <img src="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/0c9109c71ea0524d9fe840f91fabd67bb94a26a9/r=537&c=0-0-534-712/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2013/05/30/1369920769000-grumpycat-1305300933_3_4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, in cases where you want to set the width of elements as the width of the viewport/window, you could use *[viewport percentage units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)* instead. For instance:

```css
img { width: 100vw; } /* 1vw = 1/100 of the width of the viewport */
```

Demo:

```css
img { width: 100vw; }
```

```html
<img src="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/0c9109c71ea0524d9fe840f91fabd67bb94a26a9/r=537&c=0-0-534-712/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2013/05/30/1369920769000-grumpycat-1305300933_3_4.jpg"/>
<div>
  <img src="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/0c9109c71ea0524d9fe840f91fabd67bb94a26a9/r=537&c=0-0-534-712/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2013/05/30/1369920769000-grumpycat-1305300933_3_4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought this wasnt an option

Comment: @Adrian The only other possible solution is to use `vw` length. Just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this will help your problem , but technically you could do it by giving it `position:absolute;`

```
    img {
        width:100%;
    }

    div img {
        position:absolute;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100% !important;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjf8s3rq/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use dislay-inline in a way contrary to its intended use. If you want the image to take up the full width of the window, then clearly its container must also take up the full width. Which means you want your div to behave like a block element. So the solution is either to do just that and leave the div as `display:block` (its default value to start with), or at the very least you must set it's width to `width:100%`. Afterall, if you want to take up the full width of the screen then you want it to be a block.

Inline-block elements have to have their width set, either by specifying a width in the CSS, or by letting them take up as much width as they need to hold their content. In your case the image has its natural size, and your surrounding inline-block div is therefore taking up just that size and no more.

Setting width:100% on the image doesn't change that; that just tells it to take up the full with of its container, not the whole window. But  your containing div is already the natural size of the image.