# Why an image with 100% width in inline-block behaving as responsive image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am absolutely new to HTML & CSS and trying to learn it, hence this question. My target was to create a responsive image which doesn't exceed the original size of the image. Found some info on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747848/making-an-image-width100-inside-a-inline-block-element) and I was able to do it by putting the image in an inline-block which is in a div (see the code snippet), but it doesn't answer a fundamental question. How is the responsiveness working.

For the case when the viewport is larger than the image, my HTML code makes sense i.e. the width of the image is 100% which means take the size of the parent container. In this case the parent container is inline-block whose size is actually the size of the content it's enclosing, so 100% means the image will be displayed with it's original size.

But when I resize the browser window to a smaller size, the image resizes with it. Here I am not able to understand the mechanism of action. As per my info (which is limited as of now) the inline-block always takes the size of contents it's enclosing, then how come it's resizing when the outside container is changing it's size.

**Is it something that inline-block will take the size of the content TILL it's fitting in the parent container BUT as soon as the parent container is not sufficient to fill the inline-element, the inline-element will resize to the parent container and NOT the content it has in itself?**

P.S. - My first question on Stack Overflow.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive-image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inline-block">
      <img class="responsive-image" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B3Fs1er7k9QAQUU1bzhqYWMxeUU">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Kindly share your css for html and body tags as well

Comment: @Ashish: If you have satisfied with the answer given below, Please accept best answer and close the question.

Comment: @Amit: The code snippet is the entire code. I am using bootstrap's stylesheet in the body. Please check the linked stylesheets. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`width: 100%` means its width depends on its parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
.inline-block {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid purple;
 padding: 3px;
 }
```

This is a class if it will be applied on a ny div then all the elements with this class will shown inline with there side one.

```
width:100%;
```

Is something related to the total width and here total width means as much as the size of its parent div. If the size is changed something to 700px it will take 700px because of the code refers that whatever the parent div has, take that.

Answer (score 1):

**Some basics first:**

First you need to understand what is `inline`(Reference: [Inline element](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)) and what is `block` (Reference: [Block element](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp))

**Block element**: A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available i.e. *100% width*(stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).
Examples of block-level elements:

```
<div>
<h1> - <h6>
<p>
<form>
```

**Inline element** : An inline element does not start on a new line and only takes up as much width as necessary.
Examples of inline elements:

```
<span>
<a>
<img>
```

I think, by now you can get the idea what is `inline-block` means then ?

`inline-block`: Any element with `inline-block` will be displayed `inline` and will take **100% of width** available to it like what `block` element takes. Therefore, if there is any `inline` element with width say `30%` is already available and now you apply property: display as `inline-block`, then whole of leftover `70%` width will be taken. Here, leftover 70% is actually width 100% for `inline-block`

Here is the [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp).
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you set image in `width: 100%`, it will fill the width of the container where the image belongs. Even though how much width the container has.

If you specify `width:100%`, the element’s total width will be 100% of its containing block **plus** any horizontal margin, padding and border (if you specified `box-sizing:border-box`, in which case only margins are added to the 100%)