# Image inside inline-block div pushes the div down

Tags: html, css

I have two `inline-block` div elements. When i add an image inside second `div`, it pushes the div below the first `div`.

Here' the visual representation of the problem

[image]

The green colored bar should align horizontally with the blue colored side bar. I can't understand what's causing this problem.

**Question**

What is causing this problem and how can i fix this problem so that both `div` elements align exactly side by side.

Here's my code

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="top-navbar">
            <img src="../Resources/images/admin dashboard/top-bar.png" alt="top nav bar" class="image-fill"/>
        </div><!--end of top nav bar-->

        <div class="side-bar">
            <img src="../Resources/images/admin dashboard/side-bar.png" alt="side bar" class="image-fill">
        </div><!--end of side bar-->

        <div class="content-area">
            <div id="welcome-bar-container">
                <img src="../Resources/images/admin dashboard/welcome-bar.png" alt="dasboard text" class="image-fill"/>
            </div>
        </div><!--end of content area-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.side-bar {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.side-bar img {
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
}

.content-area {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: red;
    line-height: 0;
}

#dashboard-text {
    width: 70%;
}

.image-fill {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I don't see how this doesn't include the necessary code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLam Try turning the code into a snippet. No content and or the rest od the css makes this a working code example. Also, css has some rules not being used on the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.content-area` doesn't have a defined width, the `width: 100%` set on the image simply defaults to the width of the image. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747848/making-an-image-width100-inside-a-inline-block-element)

You need to set a width on the `.content-area` div to make it fit alongside the first div.

```
.content-area {
    width: 70%;
}
```

(You have `width: 70%` set for the `#dashboard-text` element, which is not used here. Did you mean to set it on the `.content-area` element?)

Comment: actually there are other elements on the web page as well which i excluded because they were not relevant to the problem and `#dashboard-text` is one of them. Anyways, you fixed my problem, thanks.

Comment: @Nick Glad it helped!